# Copy .csv file with comma (') character to postgresql table

Tags: postgresql-9.6

I have a .csv file containing numeric data that I need to copy to postgresql table, however, the field in the csv file contains (,integers). It is known that postgresql does not store characters like (,).

I have successfully copied integers without (,) but how can I copy my csv files with (example: 1,345) to postgresql table?

I successfully set this up:

```
CREATE DATABASE plants;
CREATE TABLE plantA (name varchar(50), code int, category varchar(5), count int);
```

I tried this:

```
COPY plantA FROM 'C:\Users\Desktop\Sample\plantA.csv' DELIMITER ',' csv;
```

but it gives me error:

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "1,567"
CONTEXT:  COPY planta, line 1, column count: "1,567"

********** Error **********

ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: "1,567"
SQL state: 22P02
Context: COPY planta, line 1, column count: "1,567"
```

Thank you for your help.